# Gtk, alternate color for GtkMenu items

Tags: gtk

Can we have alternate Row color to GtkMenu items?
and how to increase menu item spacing size? using Gtk+ and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492861/gtk-change-font-and-font-color-for-an-application) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649903/creating-gtk-widget-using-expander).

Comment: You have not given any example for 'this one' and 'this one'. Can u provide one example for setting Style properties programmatic and through rc file?

Comment: To be fair, you didn't ask for an example, in fact your question was quite vague. I just wanted to point out that axel_c already answered you about RC files, and we both warned you that users don't like it when you override their theme with your own RC file.

Comment: But to answer your question, it's impossible to set style properties programmatically, you can only do it through RC files. There are examples here: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Resource-Files.html